# windowTranslucentNavigation and color java android studio

Tags: java, android

Please tell me, I have an application that uses a webView in full screen. As of android 10, the navigation bar started to overlap my `webView`:

[image]

By putting `<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>`, the navigation bar stopped overlapping the webView, but I would like to make it black and but not transparent. How can I implement this? Perhaps I can do something differently so that the navigation bar does not overlap the webView? I'm new to this.

[image]

My style.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splashscreen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Thanks in advance.